# Determine the maximum likelihood estimator for $μ$

Tags: statistics

Consider the Poisson distribution with an unknown parameter $\mu$ given by
$$f(x) = \frac{ \mu^x e^{-\mu} }{x!}.$$

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are $\require{cancel}\xcancel{n \text{ samples}}$ a sample of size $n$ drawn from the Poisson distribution, determine the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$.

I'm having trouble taking the derivative since there's a factorial on the bottom of the equation.  Thanks!

Comment: The factorial is a constant, i.e. it does not depend on $\mu. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the likelihood function is a function of the *parameters* not the data $x_i$. Your likelihood function is given by:
$$\mathcal L =\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\mu^{x_i}e^{-\mu}}{x_i!}$$
We take the logarithm to make differentiation easier:
$$\log \mathcal L=\sum_i \left(x_i\log(\mu)-\mu-\log(x_i!)\right)$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\mu$ to obtain:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\log \mathcal L = \sum_i\left(\frac{x_i}{\mu}-1\right)=\frac{1}{\mu}\sum_i x_i - n$$
Set the derivative to zero to identify where the maximum of the likelihood function occurs (check for yourself that this is indeed a maximum):
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\log \mathcal L =0&\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\mu}\sum_i x_i = n\\
&\Longrightarrow \mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i
\end{align}
So your maximum likelihood estimator is:
$$\hat \mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$